# Left Join Fetch returns null with Where condition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities with `Many-to-Many` relationship: `Author` and `Book`.

I want to get a non-deleted author with all his non-deleted books (these entities have field `deleted`). And I try this `@Query`:

```
select a from Author a left join fetch a.books b
where a.id = :id and a.deleted = false and b.deleted = false
```

But it returns nothing, for example, if an author has only deleted books.

Of course, without `b.deleted = false` author is returned. But I want a query to return author without any deleted books.

How can I do that?

Maybe, with a native query?

Comment: You  can add a getter in your author object to filter if you are not dealing  with authors with thousands/millions of  books..

Comment: Have you tried a method named `findByDeletedFalseAndBooksDeletedFalse` ?

Comment: I've tried this method, it doesn't help.

Comment: I want to replace a filtering in a code with a filtering in a database.